# i m unable to know the use of (int *)

Tags: c

I'm unable to know why do we have to use typecasting `(int *)` in case of 2d array?
another thing I want to know is that why can't we use `*(*(p+i)+j))` to access the 2d array in following code? Is it always necessary to use `p + col*i + j`? Why can't I use `*(*(p+i)+j))` when `p` contains base address of array and `*(*(p+i)+j))` is equivalent to `a[i][j]`?

Thank you in advance.

```
main()
{
    int a[3][4] = {
        1,2,3,4,
        5,6,7,8,
        9,0,1,6
    };

    int *p,i,j;
    p=(int *)a;       // this is my doubt why did we use int *
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<4;j++) {
            printf("%d",*(*(p+i)+j));   // here is my 2nd doubt
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is terrible.  Where did you get it?

Comment: The question makes no sense. The code is not compilable. Expression `*(*(p+i)+j)` is invalid for a pointer `p` of type `int *`. So, it is not clear what "have to use typecasting" doing here. We don't "have" to do anything like that, but first you have to come up with a question that makes sense. What you have now sounds like "why do we have to ride bicycles underwater?"

Comment: While the code does compile - with a lot of warnings, see http://ideone.com/lfW1zp, it also crashes. Casting a to an int* might have been done to try and help show how the data is actually stored as one long sequence in memory - the layout of int[3][4] is similar to the layout of int[12]. But whoever wrote this is just bad.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not even compile, exactly where your 2nd place of doubt is. I've corrected it:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                  
int main(int argc, char *argv[])                                    
{                                                                   
    int a[3][4] = {                                                 
        1,2,3,4,
        5,6,7,8,                                                  
        9,0,1,6,
    };                                                              

    int *p, i, j;                                                   
    p = a[0];       // No cast, just address the 1st row
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {                                       
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {                                   
            printf("%d", *(p + 4*i + j));   // corrected pointer arithmetic
        }                                                           
    }                                                               
}
```

Pointer `p` does not know it's addressing a 2-dim array, it's just an int pointer.
Are you sure you want to print the numbers without even separating them by whitespace?

Comment: My version compiles and runs without crashing and prints all the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided does not compile because of line:

```
printf("%d",*(*(p+i)+j));
```

where you are dereferencing twice an int*

You can create a pointer to reference the array a of type pointer to array of 4 elements.
See the attached code where are all pointers are printed out during the execution of the nested for loop.

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    int a[3][4]={
        1,2,3,4,
        5,6,7,8,
        9,0,1,6
    };

    int (*p)[4],i,j;
    p = a;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("row pointer: %p\n",p+i);
        for(j=0;j<4;j++){
            printf("element pointer: %p\n", (*(p+i))+j );
            printf("element: %d\n",*( (*(p+i)) + j ) );
        }
    }
}
```